# How to use C# .net Serial DataReceived Handler, when reading serial port and writing data to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, serial-port

I need to continuously read a serial port, and log the data to a file, using a timer. The data is coming in fast, 4800 baud rate and I need to log the most recently read data. I am using the `DataReceivedEventHandler` and the `ReadLine()` method. The bool below, `okToReadPort` is set to `false` when the timer event occurs to write to the file. Basic code flow is below

```
...
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
...

//serial reader class
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    if (okToReadPort)
    {
        try
        {
            string indata = sp.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("NMEA Sentence read: " + indata);
            NMEAMsg tempMsg = new NMEAMsg(indata);
            int count = nmeaList.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (tempMsg.sentenceType == nmeaList[i].sentenceType)
                {
                    nmeaList[i] = tempMsg;
                }
            }
        }
     else
     //do nothing


...

//form class
...
    timerEventOccurred(){
         serialReader.okToReadPort = false; 
         writeDataToFile(serialReader.data);

}
```

I am getting an error while trying to enumerate the data list "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" it reads and writes data fine, but it seems like there are some threads that do not finish and are still reading the port when the timer event has occurred.

Does anyone have a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Probably going to need more information about when to start/stop reading the serial port and what sort of file you're writing to but have you considered having the port reading done on one thread, adding the data to a FIFO data structure and then opening a separate thread to the log that data to file?

Comment: Also it'd really help to see your `DataReceived` Handler and your `writeDataToFile` function.

Comment: i think thats the approach i will have to take. Open the serial port reading on one thread, and then when the timer event occurs to write data, open another thread to create a copy of the data and then write. thanks for your thoughts/suggesstions

Comment: Well, you are definitely modifying what looks like a collection on a worker thread.  Where is the *lock* statement you need to keep it thread-safe?

Comment: Use a ConcurrentQueue<NMEAMsg > instead of regular nmeaList collection. Use this queue inside your writeDataToFile. `while (_nmeaQueue.TryDequeue(out value))
        {
            //your processing write to file goes here
        }`